# Can I make a compound selector including this in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function that uses each to go over each element in a set and renumber them after one is removed from the DOM.

Right now that function looks like this:

```
renumber_items = function(){
  $(".item_set").each(function(index){
    $(this).find('legend').html("Item " + (index+1));
  });
};
```

I remember reading somewhere that find is a really inefficient operation, so I was wondering if there's a way to combine the 'legend' selector into a compound selector with *this*.

Comment: Probably using `.html(function)` for `$(".item_set legend")` will be more sufficient: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oxhqsvu8/).

Comment: Like `$("legend", this)` ?

Comment: @tymeJV this code will internally call `.find()`, so it is pretty much the same to `$(this).find('legend')`. [docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery-selector-context).

Comment: _"I remember reading somewhere that find is a really inefficient operation"_ - It's not in a general sense. Are you having a performance problem on your page?

Comment: Rather than worrying about `find`, a `find` inside an `each` is far less efficient than combining the two searches into one. See answer below.

Comment: @Regent: Just noticed you posted the same idea I posted only 30 mins earlier in a comment. Why don't you post it as an answer as you were the first *by far* to suggest that faster solution :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is only one `legend` per `.item_set` this will abbreviate things a bit:

```
renumber_items = function(){
  $(".item_set legend").html(function(index){
      return "Item " + (index+1);
  });
};
```

`.html` can take a function and the result is stored.

*If there is more than one `legend` per `.item_set` you will need to retain an outer each to keep the numbers sequential for each set.*

Generally if you have speed issues, on a function called many times, and the jQuery selector result is on a fixed set of elements, you just archive the search to a variable once at page load and reuse that:

```
var $legends = $(".item_set legend");
renumber_items = function(){
  $legends.html(function(index){
      return "Item " + (index+1);
  });
};
```

Comment: Well, I'm, as usually, "somewhere in comments" :) Nevertheless, your answer is more complete than my comment is, so lets just vote up your answer

Comment: Does saving the search take account for items added/removed after the search has been saved?

Comment: No. A JQuery object is just an array. That only works for a static list of elements.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try with [.filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/). As others say, it shouldn't be such a performance issue as long as you're not using it all the time. Consider labeling all the items you want to find/filter, so that you can get them all in one JQuery selector at once, and you don't have to go filtering everything after. Else you can use (as commented out by @Regent):

```
renumber_items = function(){
  $(".item_set legend").each(function(index){
    $(this).html("Item " + (index+1));
  });
};
```

Answer (score -1):

You can replace:

```
$(this).find('legend')
```

with:

```
$('legend', this)
```

The second argument sets the context in which jQuery searches for 'legend'.

If it is omitted, the context defaults to be `document`.

Comment: That is not the slowest part of the process and the speed difference between those two is negligible (it's just a short syntax).

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie Maybe, but OP asked for "combine the 'legend' selector into a compound selector with this.".

Comment: `"I remember reading somewhere that find is a really inefficient operation,"` implied they were concerned with overall efficiency. This is not significantly faster, just shorter. Sometimes you need to ignore what they ask for and give them what they need :)

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie "Give 'em what they need" your right! But using this way has an advantage: it avoids creating an unneeded jQuery object $(this), so it will be faster.

Comment: If you check the source code you will see that `$(this)` is *very* fast and does *very little*. As I said the speed difference is negligible. Suggest you run a comparison (e.g. http://jsperf.com/). This is all beside the point though as you can avoid that selector entirely :)

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie Checked :D. "negligible"", I agree.